# IM client and servers

Tags: android, server, instant-messaging

Can anyone explain how to make a basic IM client with my old PC as a server, client can be on IOS or android? And also please explain how to work with IM and servers simultaniously.

Comment: RabbitMQ with Spring AMQP could be something you should consider on your server. GCM has a maximum limit of messages.

Answer (score 0):

For android you could use [Google Cloud messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and a similar messaging service for IOS. 
When a client send's a message, it should be sent to GCM via upstream service and GCM will push the message to the server. The server will house the deviceId's of the client's and can push a message whenever required to the client by making a API call to GCM with the message and the deviceID.
Check the documentation for GCM and you will get a clear idea.
There are also other services like GCM which can work for android as well as IOS
The reason for using such a service is that it ensures that the messaging is full proof. Even if the client is not having internet connectivity or is switched off, it shall receive the message on getting internet connection. You do not have to handle those troubles!